# How to pass a ArrayList that is created in UI(items selected by user) to APIservice

Tags: android, kotlin

I have made a view on which a user can select various items after clicking on the floating action button I want to transfer this list to APIservice from where I can make the API service.
The list is being created in the view, but it is not passed.
This is the Logcat entry for the same

```
2023-06-29 16:55:05.336  1625-1625  items                   pro.shivanshtariyal.recipeapp        E  [butter, milk, cheese, eggs]
2023-06-29 16:55:05.337  1625-1625  Items recieved          pro.shivanshtariyal.recipeapp        E  []
```

How to transfer the list

I tried to make a function in the View and then call the function in the API service to receive the list.

```
    fun retItems():ArrayList<String>{

        return items //items is a global variable
    }
```

```
        var ingridients=FridgeToRecipeFragment().retItems()
```

how to do it

Comment: The other way around is probably better: Call the function in your service *from* the view/fragment.